# Question about convergence in probability

Tags: probability

The task is that "random variable $Xn$ converges to $X$ in probability, show that $Xn^2$ converges to $X^2$ in probability."
I've done tasks like "random variable $Xn$ converges to $X$ in probability, $Yn$ converges to $Y$ in probability, show that $Xn+Yn$ converge to $X+Y$ in probability." However, the method doesn't seem to work anymore and I am struggling to come up with any new clue.
Any help would be appreciated

Answer (score 0):

Use the fact that $X_n\to X$ in probability if and only if for any subsequence $X_{n_k}$ there is a further subsequence $X_{n_{k_l}}$ with $X_{n_{k_l}} \to X$ almost surely.